# WP REST API Slow performance retrieving 500+ posts

Tags: wordpress, api, rest, caching

I'm using the official WP REST API to retrieve posts. I want to retrieve all my posts (500+ posts). It takes longer than 1 minute to retrieve this!

This is way way to long to use this API in a production environment. Anyone suggestions?

I already tried W3 Total Cache with a JSON addition but without any improvements.

Comment: I don't think W3 Total Cache caches API responses (I could be wrong). You may want to setup a cache on your API client's end and only go to the API if the cache is invalidated. Maybe setup a cronjob to refresh the cache so end users never have to wait for the API response.